# Parent-child relationship efficiency

Tags: python, django, parent-child

I have an image field in one of my Django apps, but want to be able to store revisions of the image, in order to allow me to display a list in order of revision. Is the best way to do this to store the Images separately, and then to have a 'parent' ForeignKey relationship to parental images? For example:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

If there is no parent (`null=True`) then the image must have no revisions. Each object can only have one parent and one child, but the number of layers is potentially unlimited.

I don't know whether multiple layers of children can then be traversed without generating substantial numbers of SQL queries, which would make the app very inefficient. What is the best way of representing this in terms of Django objects? Is it better to have a separate 'ImageRevision' object, for example, to handle the layers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to do this efficiently:

1. Tie `Image` to the model it's used on, allowing a one-to-many for the image:

   ```
   class Image(models.Model):
       obj = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name='images')
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
       created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

       class Meta:
           ordering = ['-created']
           get_latest_by = 'created'
   ```

   Then you can get the latest revision by doing:

   ```
   my_model_instance.images.latest()
   ```
2. Create an `ImageRevision` model as you mention and tie it to `Image`.

   ```
   class Image(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   class ImageRevision(models.Model):
       parent = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name='revisions')
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
       created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

       class Meta:
           ordering = ['-created']
           get_latest_by = 'created'
   ```

   Then, you can get the latest revision with:

   ```
   my_model_instance.image.revisions.latest()
   ```

The second method involves an additional query for the additional relationship (though you should be able to mitigate that with judicious use of `select_related`), but has the benefit of being able to be used with multiple different models, whereas the first method will tie `Image` intrinsically to one model.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive, and really helpful explanation!

Answer (score 0):

What I would likely do in this case is go with the separate revisions object. Remove the parent field from the Image (as an aside, it would be a OneToOne, instead of a ForeignKey, to prevent multiple children from a single parent). So, you'd have an Image object with a name, and a revision object with the ImageField, like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Revision(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    revision_number = models.IntegerField()
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

Traversing, then does not require recursion through a chain. Something like this:

```
for i in Image.objects.all():
    print i.name
    for r in Revision.objects.filter(image=i).order_by('revision_number'):
        print "rev. " + str(r.revision_number) + " " str(r.file)
```

That is how I would handle it, at least.

Cheers